# Search for Windows 7 does not parse as expected

Tags: feature-request, search

I wanted to search for Windows 7 on SU; get a notion of what the FAQ were and so forth.

However, searching for Windows 7 yields simply Windows in the search engine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does correctly map to [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7) now, as we do a guess on the top (n) tags based on a few heuristics -- even combining words when you enter two, etc.

Answer (score 4):

How curious.  [Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-9) [for](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-8) [any](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-7) [single-digit](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-6) [number](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-5) [results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-4) [in](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-3) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-2) [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-1) [requesting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=0) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=1) [you](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=2) [enter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=3) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=4) [text](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=5) [in](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=6) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=7) [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=8) [box](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=9).

Comment: yes, all single digit numbers are stopwords

Comment: Wow, that has to be the most link per word post I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

The tag [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) definitely exists, so the search will auto replace your search with that tag. What you want to search for is [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7), which is the actual tag.

Note: Usually the response is, "Use Google." But, Google's not an Ewok yet, as evidenced by [the nothingness I found](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+7+site:superuser.com).

Comment: Yes, but I'm *expecting* a search for Windows 7 to be smartly guessed and replaced by the correct tag.

Comment: Also, Ewok? Google isn't a fuzzy sapient on a moon of Endor? No...really? O.o

Comment: @Paul: Yes, we've needled Jeff incessantly about the search. Also, it was a joke about the fact that SU is "letting in the Ewoks." Observe: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/

Comment: Clearly, it's a Monday.